# Need to Implement Click Payment Gateway - Uzbekistan

Tags: python, django, flask, payment-gateway

I need to create payment gateway Click which based on Uzbekistan PG.
this Doc link :https://docs.click.uz/en/click-api-request/
Here don't understand the implementation flow for Marchant API

there is 2 main api : 1. Prepare 2. Complete. I need to implement Marchant API, first I created create invoice API but now I don't understand the flow which api need to create first Prepare/ Complete or only merchant APIS.
From when we can get the testing data for Click PG?
here is attachment of API which implement.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import hashlib
import time
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

class ClickPay:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.baseurl            = "https://api.click.uz/v2/merchant/"
        self.secret_key         = 'AAAAAA'
        self.merchant_id        = 1111
        self.service_id         = 11111
        self.merchant_trans_id  = 11111
        self.timestamp          = str(int(time.time()))
        self.digest             = hashlib.sha1((self.timestamp + self.secret_key).encode()).hexdigest()
        self.auth               = f"{self.merchant_trans_id}:{self.digest}:{self.timestamp}"
        self.accept             = "application/json"
        self.content_type       = "application/json"
        self.headers            = {
            "Accept"        : self.accept,
            "Content-Type"  : self.content_type,
            "Auth"          : self.auth
        }
    
    def CreateInvoice(self, amount, phone_number):
        url             = f"{self.baseurl}/invoice/create"
        request_body    = {
            "service_id"        : self.service_id,
            "amount"            : amount,
            "phone_number"      : phone_number,
            "merchant_trans_id" : self.merchant_trans_id
        }
        response = requests.post(url, headers=self.headers, data=request_body)
        return response
    
    def CheckInvoiceStatus(self, invoice_id):
        url = f"{self.baseurl}/invoice/status/:{self.service_id}/:{invoice_id}"
        response = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
        return response

    def CheckPaymentStatus(self, payment_id):
        url = f"{self.baseurl}/payment/status/:{self.service_id}/:{payment_id}"
        response = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
        return response
    
    def CheckPaymentStatusByMerchantId(self):
        url = f"{self.baseurl}/payment/status_by_mti/:{self.service_id}/:{self.merchant_user_id}"
        response = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
        return response
    
    def PaymentReversal(self):
        pass
    
    def CreateCardToken(self):
        pass
    
    def VerifyCardToken(self):
        pass
    
    def PaymentWithToken(self):
        pass
    
    def DeleteCardToken(self):
        pass
    

@app.route('/create-invoice', methods=['POST'])
def create_invoice():
    amount = request.json.get('amount')
    phone_number = request.json.get('phone_number')
    
    print(amount)
    print(phone_number)

    click_pay = ClickPay()
    response = click_pay.CreateInvoice(amount, phone_number)

    return response.content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Anyone about this Uzbekistan based payment gateway Click. please regarding this.